# Crop string after 3 words

Tags: php

I have the following string:

`$msg = "Hello, my name is John!";`

I'd like to basically crop the first 3 words and store the rest in a string.

How would I achieve this? Would it be using `explode` function?

Ultimately, `$remainder` would equal: `is John!`

Comment: _"Would it be using explode function?"_ - I have a crazy idea... try it! :-)

Comment: You could $temp = explode(" ", $msg); then $temp = array_slice(2, $temp);, then $remainder = implode(" ", $temp)

Comment: Found a great solution here using `explode` & `implode`: https://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-display-certain-amount-of-words-from-stringvariable/

Comment: Please do your research and testing before asking on SO. SO is meant to be a last resort and not your go-to before having tried anything yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use `preg_replace`:

```
<?php

$msg = "Hello, my name is John!";
var_dump(preg_replace("/^([\w]+[,]?\s+){3}/", "", $msg));
```

Result:

```
string(8) "is John!"
```

Maybe you have to improve little bit regex because here word its:

at least 1 character `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _`

followed by optional `,` (comma)

followed by at least 1 space.

Answer (score 0):

As you said - you can use explode.

https://ideone.com/qpzwnV

```
$msg = "Hello, my name is John!";

$arr = explode(' ',$msg);
if(count($arr)<=3) {
    echo 'Trimmed: (empty)';
} else {
    for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) array_shift($arr);
    echo 'Trimmed: '.implode($arr, ' ');
}
```

PS: But why do you need this at all?